# R stops working/terminate when execute maximum entropy program

Tags: r, text-classification, maxent

I need your help because I don't understand why my RStudio terminater/stop working when execude maimum entropy to text classification. I using tweet data 7877 row. There is the code

```
library(tm)
library(RTextTools)
library(e1071)
library(caret)
library(ROCR)
cdr<- getwd()
setwd("E:/KULIAH")
text<- read.csv("klasifikasi tweet.csv")
set.seed(95616)
index<- sample(2, dim(text)[1], replace = T, prob = c(0.8,0.2))
text = rbind(text[index==1,], text[index==2,])
input <- text$tweet
class <- as.factor(text$kelas.)
text_mat<-create_matrix(input,language = "english", removeNumbers = TRUE,removePunctuation = F, removeStopwords =F,removeSparseTerms=0.998, stemWords = F, weighting = weightTfIdf)
train_data<- create_container(text_mat, as.numeric(class),  trainSize=1:4000, testSize=4001:4449, virgin = FALSE)
model<-train_model(train_data, "MAXENT")
result<- classify_model(train_data, model)
```

Thanks for help[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OWtz.png)

Comment: Try to run your code in `R` (not RStudio).

Comment: When it run in RGui, then R gui has stooped working

Comment: That happens to me when I'm using too heavy raster layers as environmental predictors (variables)... What are you using as variables?